# How to effectively add a call back method for the JPanel.add(component) method?

Tags: java, swing

**edit: now solved, but can't mark as accepted for two days**

In my class I have a `JScrollPanel` and that has a `JPanel` inside of it too.

My code resembles something like this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyClass {

    private JPanel p;
    private JScrollPane s;
    private Container contentPane;

    public MyClass(Container contentPane) {
        this.contentPane = contentPane;
        this.p = new JPanel();
        this.p.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(this.p, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        this.p.setLayout(boxLayout);
        this.s = new JScrollPane(this.p);
        this.s.setSize(400, 364);
        this.contentPane.add(this.s);
    }

    public final JLabel makeJLabel(String message) {
        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel("<html><p style=\"padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px;width:280px;\">" + message.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "<br />") + "</p></html>");
        /*
        some stuff here to calculate pref/max size and add an imageicon
        */
        p.add(jLabel);
        this.p.revalidate();
        this.s.revalidate(); //just added because the above line made no effect
        scrollToBottom();
        return jLabel;
    }

    public void scrollToBottom() {
        JScrollBar vertical = s.getVerticalScrollBar();
        vertical.setValue(vertical.getMaximum());
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in my class I have a method which adds a `JLabel` to the `JPanel`. This actual method is quite long, so I wont post it all, but this is the code which adds it to the panel: `p.add(jLabel1);`

All of these `JLabel`s are added in a vertical fashion thanks to the Box Layout.

After the `JLabel` has been added to the `JPanel` I want the `JScrollPane` to scroll to the bottom. But this can't be done until after the `JPanel` has actually been drawn (painted?) onto `JPanel`. Otherwise I get this result:

[image: example of scrollToBottom() being called but not working correctly]

So what I want to do is add some form of listener to the `JPanel` which detects when my JLabel has been painted to it, so that I can tell my `JScrollPane` to scroll to the bottom. I have already written a method which scrolls the pane to the bottom, but I don't have anywhere suitable to call it from yet.

Does anyone have any ideas on this please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you just want the label to be visible in the scrollpane so I would gues you should be able to do something like:

```
panel.add( label );
panel.revalidate();
label.scrollRectToVisible( label.getBounds() );
```

Or if you really do want to just scroll bo the bottom then you would do something like:

```
panel.revalidate();
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue( getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum() );
```

Both of these answers assume the GUI is already visible.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I was/am using the second solution, but the problem is that at the time of the call the component which was being added had not been added yet (it was added, but not yet painted). So the scrollbar was scrolling to the bottom, but then something extra got added (painted). I've solved it now in my post, but I can't accept my own answer for 2 days.

Comment: I read your solution. Its sounds too complicated. The painting of the component is not relevant. What is important is that all the components have been validated and have a preferred size which is why the revalidate() is important. If my suggestion doesn't work then post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem because I'm sure there is a simple way to solve the problem.

Comment: The JLabel has both a preferred size and maximum size manually set, but I still can't get this solution to work correctly. I don't know the ins and outs of how a component is added to a JPanel, but it looks as if it's scrolling to the bottom of what's visible and after scrolling the final component is added. I'll post SSCCEs now.

Comment: @kleopatra, not sure why you don't like the second. The suggestions are for two different requirments. The first to just make sure a component is visible, the second to make sure the scrollpane is at the bottom.

Comment: several reasons a) violates the general rule to always use the highest abstraction available b) code pollution by keeping a reference to the scrollPane c) digging down into referenced classes is a bad smell, either of the api or of its usage. And no, I don't think these are different use cases: The "bottom" to show is the bottom of the _panel_, not that of the scrollpane (in fact, it could be a completely different type of parent which ultimately services the requirement) To achieve that on the highest abstraction level is to scroll to a rect at the bottom of the panel

Comment: Agreed:) I was trying to suggest that if you wanted to show a specific component in the scrollpane you would use scrollRectToVisible() and if you just want to make sure the scrollpane is at the bottom (regardless of whether the panel was added to the bottom or inserted somewhere else) then you could reset the scrollbar maximum. Not sure why I mentioned the second approach given that it is not relevant to the given question and it caused cofusion :(

Answer (score 1):

The first part of Rob's answer is the way to go - the missing piece is to wrap the scrollRectToVisible into SwingUtilities.invokeLater. Doing so delays the scrolling until all pending events are processed, that is until all internal state is updated. A code snippet (in swingx test support speak, simply replace the frame creation and scrollpane wrapping with manually created code)

```
final JComponent panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    panel.add(new JLabel("initial message " + i));
JXFrame frame = wrapWithScrollingInFrame(panel, "scroll to bottom");
Action action = new AbstractAction("addMessage") {
    int count;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        final JLabel label = new JLabel("added message " + count++);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.revalidate();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                label.scrollRectToVisible(label.getBounds());
            }
        });
    }
};
frame.add(new JButton(action), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
show(frame);
```

Answer (score 0):

Scratched my head for ages over this, but after asking the question I finally figured it out.

To solve my problem all I need to do was listen for a change in value in the JScrollPane's scroll bar. If it changed, done some calculations, and scroll to the bottom if necessary.

Care has to be taken to ensure that you're not overriding the user moving the scroll bar however.
In particular you're looking at the `track` which is an `AdjustmentEvent`. This event is also fired when a user moves the scroll bar.

In order to allow the user to scroll without forcibly scroll it to the bottom, I always keep track of the maximum scroll bar value. If when track is fired the new max value is higher than the current one then a new item has been added and we should think about scrolling to the bottom. If the values are equal then the user is scrolling the scroll bar and we do nothing.

The event listeners can be found on this website and can be make to work very easily: [Listening for Scrollbar Value Changes in a JScrollPane Container](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing/scroll_SpEvt.html)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyClass {

    private JPanel p;
    private JScrollPane s;
    private Container contentPane;
    private int scrollBarMax;    

    public MyClass(Container contentPane) {

        this.contentPane = contentPane;
        this.p = new JPanel();
        this.p.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(this.p, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        this.p.setLayout(boxLayout);
        this.s = new JScrollPane(this.p);
        this.s.setSize(400, 364);
        this.contentPane.add(this.s);

        this.s.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener(){
            @Override
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    return;
                }
                if (evt.getAdjustmentType() == AdjustmentEvent.TRACK) {
                    if (scrollBarMax < s.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum()) {
                        if ((s.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue() + s.getVerticalScrollBar().getSize().height) == scrollBarMax) {
                            //scroll bar is at the bottom, show the last added JLabel
                            scrollBarMax = s.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum();
                            scrollToBottom();
                        } else {
                            //scroll bar is not at the bottom, user has moved it
                            scrollBarMax = s.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        scrollBarMax = s.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum();

    }

    public final JLabel makeJLabel(String message) {

        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel("<html><p style=\"padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px;width:280px;\">" + message.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "<br />") + "</p></html>");

        /*
        some stuff here to calculate pref/max size and add an imageicon
        */
        p.add(jLabel);
        scrollBarMax = s.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum();
        return jLabel;
    }

    public void scrollToBottom() {
        JScrollBar vertical = s.getVerticalScrollBar();
        vertical.setValue(vertical.getMaximum());
    }
}
```